# Limit of a sequence containing root of n!-th degree - how to deal with that?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Here is a sequence the limit of which I'm trying to find as $n$ goes to infinity:

$$a_n=\sqrt[n!]{\frac{1}{2^{n!}}-\frac{1}{3^{n!}}}$$

Here is what I've done:

$a_n=\sqrt[n!]{\frac{1}{2^{n!}}(1-\frac{2^{n!}}{3^{n!}})}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[n!]{1-(\frac{2}{3})^{n!}}$

Intuitevely this should converge to $\frac{1}{2}$ because as $n$ becomes large $(\frac{2}{3})^{n!}$ becomes closer and closer to $0$ so this expression under the root basically becomes $\sqrt[n!]{1}$ which is equal to $1$. I don't think I'm allowed to finish solving the problem now (as I am aware such operations can be quite risky, for example limit of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ evaluates to $e$ even though $\frac{1}{n}$ becomes closer and closer to $0$ as $n$ becomes large). So how to prove it formally?

Comment: Here, your exponent - $\frac{1}{n!}$ - also goes to $0$, hence continuity tells you the limit is $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$a_n={1\over 2} \sqrt[n!]{1-{2^{n!}\over 3^{n!}}}$$

is just a subsequence of the convergent sequence

$$b_n={1\over 2}\sqrt[n]{1-\left({2\over 3}\right)^n}$$

But then trying to directly evaluate gives $1^0$ which is not an indeterminate form, so you can just evaluate by continuity and see that you get ${1\over 2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use Squeezing. First let's get rid of the silly $n!$, it occurs everywhere. We are interested in the behaviour of $\sqrt[N]{\frac{1}{2^N}-\frac{1}{3^N}}$ for large $N$.

Note that after a short while, $\frac{1}{3^N}\lt \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2^N}$. If $N\ge 2$ then
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2^N}\lt \frac{1}{2^N}-\frac{1}{3^N}\lt \frac{1}{2^N}.\tag{1}$$
Take the $N$-th roots in (1), and observe that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sqrt[N]{1/2}=1$.

Comment: Why is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = \lim_{n!\rightarrow\infty} a_{n!}$? Can we always do that?

Comment: @qiubit this is for the same reason I cited:  it's a subsequence of a convergent sequence, André is using that implicitly when he says "for large $N$."